# Add and Remove roster in eJabberd via asp.net web application

Tags: c#, asp.net, ejabberd

Hihi, would like to automate the adding and removing of eJabberd roster from my web application on asp.net, c#. Is there any advice on this?

I have been looking and trying on jsjac and jabber-net with no luck. Appreciate any guide on this.

Thanks in advance!

:)

Comment: Far more context needed to help I think!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Eventually, I have switched my eJabberd db to MySQL, and established a connection directly into the MySQL db from my web application for manipulating all the eJabberd's actions.

:)

Answer (score 0):

you can do this by creating a new Ejabberd http Request handler module.

Create New http Request Handler Module. http://www.process-one.net/en/wiki/ejabberd_HTTP_request_handlers/ which accepts the data and processes it as you need, 
asign that module a url address in ejabberd config, then call that http-handler with a curl like serive (in php I used CURL, I don't know what is the replacement for this in ASP.NET).

Comment: thanks for the comment... I have switched my eJabberd db to MySQL, and established a connection directly into the MySQL db from my web application for manipulating all the eJabberd's actions. :)